# Split view in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm writing an Android app (I'm new to Android) which shows a list of items which you can select from and go deeper into the selections until you end up with a detail view. Now, if this was iOS I would implement a SplitViewController and have the master on the left as a navigation controller and the detail on the right. How can I achieve this on Android?

I've setup a new layout in `layout-large-land` which displays the list on the left and has a view on the right for the detail but I'm unsure how I can move from one `Activity` to another within a view. Is this even possible? How could I simulate it?

Thanks.

Comment: The following page is what you want to read: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but that requires Android 3.0 for Fragments. I'm stuck with 2.3.3 unfortunately.

Comment: I take that back. It seems Google have a compatibility library which allows fragments back to 1.6. This might be exactly what I need!